# Publishing PostGIS raster vs publish file raster in GeoServer; what's best regarding performance?

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver

I want to show high resolution raster layers in a web app (Open Layers) using GeoServer and I need to know what option is best in terms of performance.

My ideas are:

1. Publishing the raster layer as a file in GeoServer
2. Add the raster in PostGIS and use GeoServer to extract the raster from the db table.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the options, or which other options should I consider?

Comment: Really the only way to find out is to try it out. But please post an answer for others to see

Comment: There are scads of different ways to configure these solutions, so there have to be some permutations where the RDBMS is faster (though it probably involves USB 1.0 thumb drives).

Comment: You can also try it with WMS or WCS. These are standards of the OGC to put geospatial data in the web. You can also find information here https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service